# Delete columns with almost specific name

Tags: r

I have a d data frame and I want to delete columns which have almost the same name. Example col, col1, col2 .... coln

I tried something like this:

```
 d$coln <- NULL
```

but it works only for the last coln column.

Comment: `d[!grepl("col", names(d))]`

Answer (score 6):

Use `grep` to identify the columns and `list(NULL)` to remove them.

Some sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(id_1 = 1:6, id_2 = c("A", "B"), varA.1 = sample(letters, 6), 
                   varA.2 = sample(letters, 6), varA.3 = sample(letters, 6),
                   varB.2 = sample(10, 6), varB.3 = sample(10, 6),
                   varC.3 = rnorm(6))
mydf
#   id_1 id_2 varA.1 varA.2 varA.3 varB.2 varB.3      varC.3
# 1    1    A      g      y      r      4      3 -0.04493361
# 2    2    B      j      q      j      7      4 -0.01619026
# 3    3    A      n      p      s      8      1  0.94383621
# 4    4    B      u      b      l      2     10  0.82122120
# 5    5    A      e      e      p     10      6  0.59390132
# 6    6    B      s      d      u      1      2  0.91897737
```

Let's remove all columns that have a "varA" in them.

```
mydf[grep("varA", names(mydf))]
mydf[grep("varA", names(mydf))] <- list(NULL)
mydf
#   id_1 id_2 varB.2 varB.3      varC.3
# 1    1    A      4      3 -0.04493361
# 2    2    B      7      4 -0.01619026
# 3    3    A      8      1  0.94383621
# 4    4    B      2     10  0.82122120
# 5    5    A     10      6  0.59390132
# 6    6    B      1      2  0.91897737
```

Comment: You could also use `mydf[grep("varA", names(mydf),invert=TRUE)]` to only return the columns that do *not* match.

Comment: @thelatemail, sure, but that doesn't destructively delete. You'll need to reassign to a new object (which, for the casual user, is probably a better thing than fully getting rid of the columns from the source `data.frame`).